# How to prevent going back to the secured page after logout in symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching

In my symfony site after logout, when I click on the browser's back button it is redirecting to the previous secured page.Is there any way to prevent that.I made a thorough search on that but nothing helped me.As per some suggestions added no-cache header tags but didn't work.I know it is the cached copy of the file.But I don't think it is fair to show a secured page after logout even if it is a cached copy.I have checked in some major sites like twitter, facebook and linkedin they are working as normal never showing a cached copy after logout.
This is my firewall settings,

firewalls:

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/(?!administrator)
        form_login:
              provider: fos_userbundle
              login_path:     /
              use_forward:    false
              check_path:     /user/login_check
              success_handler: evp.security.authentication_handler
              failure_handler: evp.security.authentication_handler
              failure_path:   /user/login
              always_use_default_target_path: true
              default_target_path: /user/login_redirect
              remember_me:    true
        fos_facebook:
              app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/test"
              server_url: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              login_path: /user/login
              check_path: /facebook/login_check
              provider: fos_facebook_provider
              default_target_path: /user/facebook_login
        fos_twitter:
              login_path: /user/login
              check_path: /twitter/login_check
              default_target_path: /user/twitter_login
              provider: my_fos_twitter_provider
        remember_me:
              key:      %secret%
              lifetime: 31536000
              path:     ~
              domain:   ~
              remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
              user_provider: fos_userbundle
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                twitter:           "/login/check-twitter" 
            login_path:        /login
            failure_path:      /login

            oauth_user_provider:
                service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider
        logout:
            path: /user/logout
            target: /
        anonymous: true
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/administrator
        provider: main
        form_login:
            login_path:  /administrator
            check_path:  /administrator/login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /administrator/dashboard
        anonymous: ~
        logout:
            path:  /administrator/logout
            target: /administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your security.yml, your symfony2 version and many other details but if you have a `app\config\security.yml` like mine (on symfony 2.5.2):

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    your_firewall_name:
        provider: your_provider # for users stored on DB
        context: context_name
        host: your_host_name
        pattern: ^/ # to protect the whole domain/subdomain
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            # Login paths:
            login_path: your_login_route
            check_path: your_login_check_route
            # Login success options
            use_referer: false
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: your_default_target_path
            # Login failed options
            failure_path: your_login_route
            remember_me: false # to disable remember me
        logout:
            # Logout paths
            path: your_logout_route
            target: your_target_route_after_logout
            # Logout options
            invalidate_session: true # the authenticated session will be unavailable afterwards

access_control:
    - { host: your_host_name, path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET] }
    - { host: your_host_name, path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [POST] }
    - { host: your_host_name, path: ^/logout, roles: ROLE_USER, methods: [GET] }
    - { host: your_host_name, path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

when you click on go-back button you'll be redirected to `your_login_route`, **but you haven't any chance to delete the other previous pages cached on the browser-side** (if you click the Go-Back page many times) **as also happens in large sites such as ebay**.
The important thing is that pages will not work because you are no longer authenticated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.My symfony version is 2.3. I have tried the your_login_route but didn't help.Added my firewall settings.

Comment: please add your `access_control` too. Have you tried my strategy on your `secured_area`?

Comment: Not added any access_control but secured every functions with $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_PROVIDER'). I tried it in my secured area also.But not working.

Comment: `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_PROVIDER')` and `access_control` directives are not the same thing, take a look at [authentication and authorization from the symfony 2.3 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/security.html). You need these directives to redirect automatically all anonymous users pointing to any route under your `secured_area` firewall.
For sure my strategy works if you uses it as-is but I think there are too many missing details to give a more useful response. It would be also useful to know what returns `app/console router:debug`